# how to store matrix from input

Tags: c, matrix

I am given matrix in this input format:

```
-1 2 3\n
 5 9 11\n
 3 4 5\n
```

So in words it is: N integers where row is ended by user pressing enter (\n in the example) after each row.

I have to check for valid input so if user enters anything besides numbers and white space, (space, new line, tab `'\t'` and character `-` for negative integers), it is invalid (including `+` sign), output of the program should determine if it is NxN matrix.

The way I am thinking is to read it by characters until last read character is '\n' and store them in 2-dimension array (for future use), save number of stored numbers so I can check in the future if it was NxN.

Is this good approach or is there something smarter?

Comment: I think it simply nice fgets & sscanf If N is given in advance.

Comment: Do you know the value of N in advance?

Comment: No its not known in advance

Answer (score 0):

That seems like a decent approach... but you don't need to store them — you just need to check if it either ends before N rows or after N rows.

- If the number of entries per row varies, then return false.
- If the matrix ends before the number of rows == the number of columns, return false.
- If the number of rows surpasses the number of columns, return false.
- If it breaks any of your character rules, return false.

EDIT: MY bad, just pulled a dum-dum and realized you actually wanted to store it and not just check it. The same thing applies, but after reading the first row into an array you made of some maximum size, you can allocate a new 2-dimensional `char` array with `malloc`, and then just break if it won't fit for some reason.

Comment: and do i have to read numbers as characters for example input of first row is 1000 -2 3 it would work like: read c save it to tmp converted to number, and do this (tmp *= tmp*10 + c) and wait until '\n' or '\t' or ' ' then i know its end of number and return it, so i can store it, but what happens if user inputs few numbers and return eof (Ctrl-D in terminal) if he enters only one numnber that should be valid input since it is 1x1 matrix and is square matrix